# Complete and elementary proof that $(a^x - 1)/x $ converges as x goes to 0

Tags: calculus, limits

Anybody who has taken a calculus course knows that
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{a^x - 1}{x}$$
exists for any positive real number $a$, simply because the limit is by definition the derivative of the function $a^x$ at $x = 0$.  However, for this argument to be non-circular one must have an independent technique for proving that $a^x$ is differentiable.  The standard approach involves the following two steps:

1) Calculate the derivative of $\log_a x$ by reducing it to the calculation of
$$\lim_{h \to 0} (1 + h)^{\frac{1}{h}}$$

2) Apply the inverse function theorem.

I find this unsatisfying for two reasons.  First, the inverse function theorem is not entirely trivial, even in one variable.  Second, the limit in step 1 is quite difficult; in books it is often calculated along the sequence $h = \frac{1}{n}$ where $n$ runs over the positive integers, but doing the full calculation seems to be quite a bit more difficult (if one hopes to avoid circular reasoning).

So I would like a different argument which uses only the elementary theory of limits and whatever algebra is needed.  For instance, I would like to avoid logarithms if their use involves an appeal to the inverse function theorem.  Is this possible?

Comment: When you really get down to it, as I think you are trying to do here, what is your definition of $a^x$? If you want to dig that deep, you will need to recognize that $a^x$ is generally a pretty tough thing to define without calculus when $x$ is a general real number.

Comment: You can define it as $a^x = \inf \{a^{r} : r>x, r\in Q\}$.

Comment: Yes, that's how I want to define it: give an algebraic definition on $\mathbb{Q}$, prove that the function so defined is continuous on $\mathbb{Q}$ with the standard metric, and define $a^x$ to be the unique continuous extension to $\mathbb{R}$.  None of this involves anything all that much more sophisticated than the definition of a limit.

Comment: Of course, I don't know an answer even with most other definitions of $a^x$.  One way is to first define logarithms using integrals, but this ends up using the fundamental theorem of calculus and the inverse function theorem.  Another way is to define $e^x$ as the unique solution to the ODE $y' = y$, but this uses the existence/uniqueness theorem for ODE's which is just as hard as the inverse function theorem.  The only definition I can think of which makes this limit transparent is via power series.

Comment: OK, but what do you mean by "the unique continuous extension to $\mathbb{R}$"? Do you want to get down to the business of establishing that there is a unique continuous extension? Separate comment: using power series would also be circular. Either you are relying on knowing the derivative of $a^x$ to get the power series, or you are defining the $a^x$ by its power series but then what is the meaning of the $\ln(a)$'s in the coefficients?

Comment: It is a standard (and fairly easy) fact that any continuous function on a dense subspace of a metric space extends uniquely to a continuous function on the whole space.  Certainly this fact is no harder than constructing $\mathbb{R}$ in the first place.

Comment: It is easy to show that the power series $1 + x + x^2/2! + \ldots$ converges to a function $f(x)$ on the whole real line, and that this function satisfies $f(x) = f(1)^x$ for any rational number $x$.  From there it is easy to show that $f(x)$ is invertible, and a definition of $a^x$ for any positive $a$ follows immediately.

Comment: I guess I don't see why you are willing to take things like construction of the reals (something that some highly regarded mathematicians think is nonsense) and convergence of power series as established and 'easy', but the inverse function theorem and fundamental theorem of calculus are off limits. I'll bow out of this thread.

Comment: If we do not accept the construction of the reals, then there is no real point in trying to do calculus in the first place.  But aside from that, your objections are contradictory: my question need not involve very many real numbers (one can define $a^x$ for rational $x$ just by taking $n$th roots), so it stands to reason that tools like the inverse function theorem and FTC - both of which use the completeness axiom for $\mathbb{R}$ nontrivially - should be overkill.  If you think there are doubts about $\mathbb{R}$, why are you comfortable using these theorems?

Comment: @PaulSiegel: what you call a standard and fairly easy fact, that a continuous function on a dense subset of a metric space extends uniquely to a continuous function on the whole space, is false. Try $f(x) = 1/(x^2-2)$ on ${\mathbf Q}$ as a subset of ${\mathbf R}$.

Comment: In my undergraduate analysis course in college, a student said that a continuous function on a metric space always extends by continuity to the completion and the instructor asked "Would you like to bet your college tuition on that?"

Comment: Arg! I'd like to just pretend that I said "uniformy continuous on precompact sets"... :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prove that

$$\lim_n \left( 1+\frac{1}{n} \right)^n = \lim_n\left( 1+\frac{1}{n} \right)^{n+1}$$

exists, and call this limit $e$. The reason why these two limit exists is because it can be proven with the Bernoulli inequality that $\left( 1+\frac{1}{n} \right)^n$ is increasing and $\left( 1+\frac{1}{n} \right)^{n+1}$ is decreasing.
It follows that they are both convergent, and their ratio converges to $1$, thus the limit exists.

From here, we also get immediately that

Now, for each $x \in (0, \infty)$ we have $\lfloor x \rfloor \leq x <  \lfloor x \rfloor  +1$. For simplicity I will denote $n:=\lfloor x \rfloor$. Then, we get

$$\left( 1+\frac{1}{n+1} \right)^n \leq \left( 1+\frac{1}{x} \right)^x \leq \left( 1+\frac{1}{n} \right)^{n+1}$$

As $n \to \infty$ when $x \to \infty$, by a squeeze type argument we get

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \left( 1+\frac{1}{x} \right)^x=e$$

Using $1-\frac{1}{x}=\frac{x-1}{x}=\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{x-1}}$ we also get

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \left( 1-\frac{1}{x} \right)^x=e^{-1}$$

and then

$$\lim_{y \to 0} \left( 1+y \right)^\frac{1}{y} =e$$

Let $y=a^x-1$ [Note: no logarithms are used here, we just use the fact that if the limit exists for all $y \to 0$, it also exists for this articular choice of $y$.]

Then, we get

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \left( a^x \right)^\frac{1}{a^x-1} =e$$

Thus, we proved that

$$\lim_{x \to 0} a^\frac{x}{a^x-1} =e \,,$$

exists. At this point logarithms would solve the problem, but you can probably finish the argument without using logarithms. For example, you can prove that $a^y$ is strictly increasing/decreasing (which reduces to $x >y \Rightarrow a^{x-y} >1$) and prove the following lemma:

**Lemma** If $f$ is strictly monotonic and continuous,  and for some $c$ the limit 
$$\lim_{x \to c} f(g(x))$$
exists, then $\lim_{x \to c} g(x)$ exists.

Comment: This looks very nice - I even don't mind using logarithms in the last step since all that is really used is the continuity and invertibility of $a^x$.

Answer (score 0):

The most common definition of $e$ is $$e:=\lim_{x\to0}\left(1+x\right)^{1/x}$$ although you often see it with $n=1/x$ and as $n\to\infty$.
Now $$\begin{aligned}\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{e^x-1}{x}\right)&=\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{\left(\lim_{y\to0}\left(1+y\right)^{1/y}\right)^x-1}{x}\right)\\
&=\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{\lim_{y\to0}\left(1+y\right)^{x/y}-1}{x}\right)\\
&=\lim_{x\to0}\lim_{y\to0}\left(\frac{\left(1+y\right)^{x/y}-1}{x}\right)
\end{aligned}$$ 
Now are you willing to believe that $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\left(\frac{\left(1+y\right)^{x/y}-1}{x}\right)
$$ exists? If so it equals the last line above, and it also equals  $$\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{\left(1+x\right)^{x/x}-1}{x}\right)
$$ by tracking along the line $y=x$. This last quantity is clearly $1$. From here, you can establish that the derivative of $e^x$ is $e^x$, from which the Chain Rule gives that the derivative of $a^x$ is $a^x\ln(a)$, from which you can get that $\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{a^x-1}{x}\right)=\ln(a)$.

See if you can find justification for the existence of that limit as $(x,y)\to(0,0)$.

Comment: Your argument seems to exploit the continuity of the function $((1+y)^{x/y}-1)/x$ which, as far as I can tell, is no easier than the original problem.

Answer (score 0):

From the identity

$$ \frac{a^{x} - 1}{x} = \frac{a^{x/n} - 1}{x/n} \cdot \frac{1}{n} \cdot \left(1 + a^{x/n} + a^{2x/n} + \cdots + a^{(n-1)x/n} \right)$$

it shouldn't be terribly hard to show that the limit exists (although it might be a bit tedious to work through all of the detail). I can't say how illuminating this approach would be, though.

Comment: This is a compelling observation, but it is not clear how exactly to exploit it.

Comment: @Paul: The proof sketch I have in mind is: (1) prove that it converges when $x$ is restricted to the sequence $x_n = 1/n!$. (2) prove it for $x$ restricted to positive rationals. (3) prove it for $x$ restricted to nonzero rationals. (4) prove the limit. Point (2), I think, is the only tricky part, and I think it can be done by using the fact we can make $a^x$ arbitrarily close to 1 by forcing $x$ sufficiently small.

Answer (score 0):

This question is ultimately related to conceptual foundation of exponentiation and logarithm. The limit of $(a^{x} - 1)/x$ as $ x \to 0$ requires that we first define the symbol $a^{x}$. This itself is a tough problem (for a beginner in calculus) and there are many approaches possible. Based on the question given here, one possible approach goes like this.

1) Let $f(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty}n(x^{1/n} - 1)$. Then it can be shown (using various theorems on limits and nothing else) that this limit exists for all $x > 0$ and hence defines a function $f(x)$ which has following properties:

- $f(1) = 0$
- $f(xy) = f(x) + f(y)$
- $f(x)$ is strictly increasing
  function of $x$ and maps the domain $(0, \infty)$ into range
  $(-\infty, \infty)$

2) Next we can use the inverse function theorem to define a new function $g(x)$ such that $y = g(x)$ and $x = f(y)$ are equivalent. Let $e = g(1)$ so that $f(e) = 1$ and then we define function $a^{x} = g(xf(a))$.

3) It can then be proved that $\lim_{x \to 0}(a^{x} - 1)/x = f(a)$ and $\lim_{h \to 0}(1 + h)^{1/h} = e = g(1)$

In traditional notation $f(x)$ is represented by $\log x$ and $g(x)$ is represented by $e^{x}$ or $\exp(x)$. The above presentation does not involve any circular reasoning, but does require the deep conceptual framework of real numbers and limits. Even at the beginning of this presentation we need to know the meaning of $x^{1/n}$ which can not be given without the completeness property of real numbers.

**UPDATE:** After looking at OP's comments on my answer I think what is needed here is to show that the limit $\lim_{x \to 0}(a^{x} - 1)/x$ exists under the following definition of $a^{x}$:

If $x$ is rational then $a^{x}$ can be defined to some extent via algebra as is done in courses of elementary algebra.

If $x$ is irrational then let $x_{n}$ be a sequence of rationals tending to $x$ as $ n \to \infty$ and then we define $a^{x} = \lim_{n \to \infty}a^{x_{n}}$.

This definition is intuitive but has technical challenges namely a) to show that $\lim_{n \to \infty}a^{x_{n}}$ exists and also show that b) if $x_{n}, y_{n}$ are rational and $x_{n} \to x, y_{n} \to x$ then $\lim_{n \to \infty}a^{x_{n}} = \lim_{n \to \infty}a^{y_{n}}$

Using this definition we can proceed as follows:

1) Show that if $x_{n}$ is a sequence of reals tending to $x$ then $a^{x} = \lim_{n \to \infty} a^{x_{n}}$

2) Show that $\lim_{x \to 0} a^{x} = 1$

3) Using 2) above show that it is sufficient to consider $x \to 0+$ when calculating $\lim (a^{x} - 1)/x$

4) Establish that $\lim_{n \to \infty}n(a^{1/n} - 1) = L$ exists. Use this to find bounds for $a^{1/n}$ like $a^{1/n} = 1 + \{(L + \phi(n))/n\}$ where $\phi(n)$ to zero as $n \to \infty$

5) Using 4) above estimate $a^{x}$ for small $x$ i.e. for $1/(n + 1) < x < 1/n$ and then show that $(a^{x} - 1)/x$ also tends to $L$ as $x \to 0+$.

All this can be done rigorously with epsilon-delta type arguments. Proving 4) will require the theorem that bounded and monotone sequences are convergent. Thus we can provide a rigorous proof that $\lim_{x \to 0}(a^{x} - 1)/x$ exists for all $a > 0$ and use this limit as definition of $\log a$ if one so desires.

Comment: Well, this is an attempt to solve the problem by defining it away.  As I wrote in the comments above, I want to use the most naive definition of $a^x$: first define it on rational numbers using algebra, then extend to the reals by continuity.

Comment: To Paul Siegel: The approach you mention for defining $a^{x}$ is intuitive, but difficult technically. What I presented was one way of doing things. I still prefer to start the definition of these stuff with $\log x = \int_{1}^{x}(1/t)\,dt$ as this is the easiest approach with very simple proofs of almost all properties of logarithm and exponents.

Comment: To Paul Siegel: In case you define $a^{x}$ first for rational $x$ and then for irrational $x$ by continuity, then you need to also define the function $\log x$ suitably. If you provide a definition of $\log x$ in your approach then I think it should be possible to supply an easy proof of $\lim_{x \to 0}(a^{x} - 1)/x = \log a$

Answer (score 0):

If we know,
from the properties of exponents,
 that
$f(x) = a^x$
satisfies
$f(x+y) = f(x)f(y)$,
then
$f(x+h)-f(x)
=a^{x+h}-a^x
=a^xa^h-a^x
=a^x(a^h-1)
$
so
$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}
=a^x\frac{a^h-1}{h}
=a^x\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}
$.

All we need,
therefore,
is that
$a^x$ is differentiable at $0$.

Then,
as has been said in other solutions,
we have to look at
some foundation stuff.

Comment: I'm not sure this is helpful: my question could be rephrased as "how can one prove that $a^x$ is differentiable at $0$ using only elementary techniques?"  But I don't think foundational issues are all that relevant here: there is no problem defining $a^x$ on $\mathbb{Q}$, and it can be extended to $\mathbb{R}$ by continuity.  If you like, I would be happy with an argument which calculates the limit along all sequences of rational numbers.